# (Discord.JS) if(message.author.id Problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to detect a "> hr" as soon as it detects it, it checks if the bot (with its id) answers well if yes it checks its content and sends a mp to the user

Except that I am blocked to send a dm to the user who marked the command because I simply do not respect the condition that checks the bot with its id.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    message.channel.messages.fetch({around: message.id, limit: 1}).then((messages) => {
        messages.forEach((msg) => {
          if (msg.content === ">hr" || msg.content === ">hourly") {
              const messager = mesg.author()
              message.channel.send('Reviens dans 1 heures Pour réclamer ton hr')
            if(message.author.id === '280726849842053120') {
               if(message.content.includes('- You gained:')) {
                 msg.author.send('test')
                }
         }          
          }
       })
      })
```

Comment: You are fetching the messages each and every time when someone sends a message. That's an API spam.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to detect message with content ">hr" it should be like :

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === ">hr" || message.content === ">hourly") {
        message.channel.send('Reviens dans 1 heures Pour réclamer ton hr')
    }
    if(message.author.id === '280726849842053120') {
        if(message.content.includes('- You gained:')) {
            message.author.send('test')
        }
    }
})
```